# How do i remove all the dots from a number in a string using regex in a dataframe?

Tags: regex, apache-spark

Suppose I have a column (in PySpark) with the values like this:

```
column_a
force is N 12.555.335 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99
weight is 5.704.149 lbs and height is 57.89
5.635.622 lbs of weight 
Acid is 2.395
```

In all of these rows, I want to remove decimals where there are 3 digits after the decimal. For example, 12.555.335 changes to 12555335, 2.395 changes to 2395. But, the number with only 2 digits after decimal remains the same. So, my final output would be:

```
column_a
force is N 12555335 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99
weight is 5704149 lbs and height is 57.89
5635622 lbs of weight 
Acid is 2395
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, have you done `if s.count(".") >=2`, then replace the periods for each string `s` in the column?

Comment: but, you can have a string in other parts of the string, example: "force is N 12.5.33 weight and. second force is 12N 67.87.99" So, it's hard.

Comment: Then use a regex to count `\d+\.\d+?`

Comment: This only takes care of 1 dot, I need 2 dots to fix this.

Comment: @emma19: Did you make any attempt at it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a UDF. Therefore, I suggest you try with plain Python first.

For example,

```
import re

def replace_dots(s):
    matches = re.finditer(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)
    
    data = []
    start = end = None
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        start = match.start()
        if end is not None:
            # have data from previous iteration, so add up to the new match
            data.append(s[end:start])
        else:
            # default case, we're starting from the start of the string
            data.append(s[:start])
        end = match.end()
        # add a whole match without the periods
        data.append(s[start:end].replace(".", ''))
        
    # might have left-over data after the final match
    data.append(s[end:])
    
    return ''.join(data)

# decimal followed by 3 or more digits, followed by an optional decimal
regex = r"(.\d{3,}\.?)"
test_strs = [
    "force is N 12.5.33 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99",
    "weight is 5.704.149 lbs and height is 57.89",
    "5.635.622 lbs of weight",
    "Acid is 2.395"
]

for s in test_strs:
    print(replace_dots(s))
```

Output

```
force is N 12555335 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99
weight is 5704149 lbs and height is 57.89
5635622 lbs of weight
Acid is 2395
```

Keep in mind, if you had sentences like `This number is 12.345.`, Then that would remove the trailing period...

Comment: Actually this is a pyspark data frame not python array of strings.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It was only an example. You can [register the shown function as a PySpark UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/), then apply to a dataframe column.

Answer (score 0):

Do just that. Use look ahead assertion to replace dot only if it is followed by 3 dibgits. Code below

```
df.withColumn('column_a_edited', regexp_replace('column_a', '\.(?=\d{3})','')).show(truncate=False)


+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |column_a                                                     |column_a_edited                                            |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |force is N 12.555.335 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99|force is N 12555335 weight and second force is 12N 67.87.99|
|2  |weight is 5.704.149 lbs and height is 57.89                  |weight is 5704149 lbs and height is 57.89                  |
|3  |5.635.622 lbs of weight                                      |5635622 lbs of weight                                      |
|4  |Acid is 2.395                                                |Acid is 2395                                               |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```